# How to compare default struct value (no null)? Why this code does not work?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, comparison, key-value

How to get the default value of a struct, why this code does not work?

```
KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, Alarm>  kvpAlarmDuplicate = lastestUniqueAlarms.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.OriginalUniqueMessage == originalUniqueMsg);
                    
if (kvpAlarmDuplicate == default(KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, Alarm>)) // Here error*
{
        ...
}
                    
Error* => CS0019 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 
  'KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, Alarm>' and
  'KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, Alarm>'
```

**How to know if the returned value is the default one?**

Additional info (I don't know if it is useful, just in case)?  =>

```
[Table("alarm")]
public class Alarm
{
    public Alarm()
    {
    }

    public static TimeSpan DelayDuplicateOccurence { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

    public int AlarmId { get; set; } 
    ...
```

Comment: I would just compare the keys and values separately. `kvpAlarmDuplicate.Key == default && kvpAlarmDuplicate.Value == default`

Comment: You can use something like `kvpAlarmDuplicate.Key == default && kvpAlarmDuplicate.Value is null`

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is not meant to be used directly and outside the context of `IDictionary`. It's more like a helper type. Collections that depend on `KeyValuePair` like the `Dictionary` provide the equality rules for an entry, therefore it doesn't implement `IEquatable` to implement its own rules. `KeyValuepair` is used in multiple types that have different equality rules for an entry. I recommend using `ValueTuple` instead. The `ValueTuple` has generally a better perfomance than `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: You also can easily convert a `KeyValuePair`to a `ValueTuple` for the equality comparison. For example: `bool isEqual = (kvpAlarmDuplicate.Key, kvpAlarmDuplicate.Value) == default;`.

Comment: Or simply call the `object.Equals` method instead of using the equality operator: `bool isEqual = kvpAlarmDuplicate.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<DateTimeOffset, Alarm>));`.

Comment: @BionicCode, thanks a lot. I used object.Equals.

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy I could help. But you should note that `object.Equals` can result in bad performance. I suggested it because the type `KeyValuePair` only defines two fields. But in geneal you have to be careful when using this equality comparison. This is because `object.Equals` does not know the instance type. That's why `object.Equals` must use reflection to get *all* fields of a type for a one-by-one value comparison.

Comment: Because this is an equality comparison that requires two operands, reflection is applied twice, once for each type of the comparison. Reflection is generally slow.  If your comparison is invoked frequently e.g., inside a loop, then you should consider to use ValueTuple (as shown in my second comment).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I haven't realized that it is using reflection. I will verify the usage or future usage too. I really appreciated. That's the best usage and advantage of stack overflow. Thanks